# How to read data from axios response through module.exports?

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, axios

I need to read data from axios response through module.export.
This is my data:
**http://localhost:8001**

```
{
    "name":"Nama Nih",
    "desc":"Sekolah Terpadu Al-Qudwah - Yayasan Islam Qudwatul Ummah",
    "prefix":"alqudwah",
    "footerText":"Yayasan Islam Qudwatul Ummah | All Rights Reserved 2020",
    "logoText":"Al-Qudwah",
    "needLogin":false
}
```

I call data from axios with this code:
**brand.js**

```
var axios = require('axios');

module.exports = axios.get('http://localhost:8001', {
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }})
  .then(function (response) {
    return response.data;
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
  .then(function () {
  });
```

But when I read response data it's not like expected. I try to console log return value like this:
[image]

This is my code where I console.log the response.

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import brand from 'ba-api/brand';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';

class Dashboard extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    console.log(brand);
    const title = brand.name + ' - Dashboard';
    const description = brand.desc;
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <Helmet>
          <title>{title}</title>
          <meta name="description" content={description} />
          <meta property="og:title" content={title} />
          <meta property="og:description" content={description} />
          <meta property="twitter:title" content={title} />
          <meta property="twitter:description" content={description} />
        </Helmet>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Dashboard.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(Dashboard);
```

How to read this data?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't export directly the fetched data. Technically you could achieve something similar by:

- [performing a sync http request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests)
- wrapping the http function call inside an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

**NOTE:** The following is not a best-practice approach. In a React component, prefer the `suggested` method.

```js
// brand.js
module.exports = (() => {
   const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
   request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8001', false);
   request.send(null);

   if (request.status === 200) {
     return request.responseText;
   }
})();
```

### Suggested approach

If you can live without having synchronously access to the requested resource, you can wrap axios in a custom hook.

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const useAxios = (url) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
       .get(url)
       .then(({ data }) => setState({ data }))
       .catch(error => setState({ error }));     
  }, []);

  return state;
}

// .. in your component
const Component = () => {
   const { data, error } = useAxios('http://localhost:8001');

   if (error) {
     ... error component
   }

   if (!data) {
     ... loading component
   }

   return (
     ... component that is consuming `data`
   );
}
```

In your specific case, as you are using that data only for setting metas, you can skip the error and loading components.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Based on trial and error, I found solution I have answered above.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this question with this solution:
***brand.js***

```
var axios = require('axios');

const sendGetRequest = async () => {
  try {
      const resp = await axios.get('http://localhost:8001', {
        headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }})
        .then(function (response) {
          return response.data;
        });
      return resp;
} catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
  }
};

module.exports = sendGetRequest();
```

And I call that function with this code:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import brand from 'ba-api/brand';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';

class Dashboard extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: '',
      description: ''
    }  
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    brand.then(data => {
      this.setState({
        title: data.name,
        description: data.desc
      });  
    });
  }
  render() {
    const title = this.state.title + ' - Dashboard';
    const description = this.state.description;
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <Helmet>
          <title>{title}</title>
          <meta name="description" content={description} />
          <meta property="og:title" content={title} />
          <meta property="og:description" content={description} />
          <meta property="twitter:title" content={title} />
          <meta property="twitter:description" content={description} />
        </Helmet>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Dashboard.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(Dashboard);
```

Thank you for all who responses my question.