# How to Export Axios Response on Module Export ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I need to export result of axios response on module.exports.
This is my codes:

**brand.js**

```js
var axios = require('axios');

module.exports = (async function() {
    try {
        const { data } = axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/setting/index');
        console.log(data.data.initial);
        return {
            name: data.data.name,
            desc: data.data.description,
          };      
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }      
})();
```

I try to import the result to be used on another file.
This is my code.

```js
import React from 'react';
const {brand} = await require("brand.js");
  
class Dashboard extends Component {   
    render(){
        const name = brand.name
        const desc = brand.description;
        return (
        <h1>{title} | {description}</h1>
        );        
    }
}
```

The result of my code is:

```
Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function
```

This is error shown on browser:

[image]

How to solved this?

Comment: Have you tried putting `await` before `axios.get()` in brand.js instead of before `require()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [exporting after promise finishes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49073048/exporting-after-promise-finishes)

Comment: You have to use `.then()` on the imported (required) Promise object.

Comment: I have added await in front of axios, but error still exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this.

```js
// brand.js

import axios from 'axios';

export const fetchData = async () => {
  let response;

  try {
    response = await axios.get(url, config);
  } catch (e) {
    // catch error
    throw new Error(e.message)
  }

  // if success return value
  return response?.data ? response?.data : null // or set initial value
}
```

then in your React

```js
import { fetchData } from './path/to/fetchData';

const response = fetchData();

const MyComponent = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>name: {response.data.name} | desc: {response.data.description}</div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually this is my repeated question, I get my answer from my another question. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64350949/how-to-read-data-from-axios-response-through-module-exports